# How to import gpx file from Google Drive on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, gpx

I've tried to add bottom code in info.plist. But it still couldn't work.

My project needs to support gpx file. It works on Email, GMail, Files, etc., but Google Drive could not.

I find "Gaia GPS" & "ViewRanger" are same situation.

On the other hand, Android could do that.

Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks!

**My steps are**

Step 1: Open Google Drive app

Step 2: Select the file I want

Step 3: Click "..." button & "Open in" button

Result: I could not find my app in app list.

**Environment**

Google Drive Version: v 4.2018.46202

iOS Version: 12.1 (16B5089b)

XCode Version: 10.1 (10B61)

**Info.Plist**

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>GPX File</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.GPX</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.text</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>GPX Document</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>public.gpx</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>gpx</string>
        </array>
        <key>public.mime-type</key>
        <string>text/gpx</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I also try to the other mime-type

```
<key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/gpx+xml</string>
</dict>
```

or

```
<key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/gpx</string>
</dict>
```